# Anylogic NullPointer Jar file has no attachment

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, anylogic

My road traffic model is throwing null pointers with a very cryptic stacktrace:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.anylogic.libraries.road.Car_xjal.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.road.Car_xjal.al(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.road.Car_xjal.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.road.Car_xjal.on_SegmentEndEvent_xjal(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.road.Car_xjal$SegmentEndEvent.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.cl(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$n.run(Unknown Source)
```

The null pointer also doesn't happen immediately, I am able to see the model run for varying lengths of time(60-800 model seconds).

When a breakpoint is created, it says the following:

```
The JAR file C:\Program Files\AnyLogic 8.8 Professional\plugins\com.anylogic.road_traffic_library_8.8.1.202210270952\lib\RoadTrafficLibrary.jar
 has no source attachment. You can attach a source by clicking Attach Source below
```

It also occasionally throws the same error, but citing a different path("C:\Program Files\AnyLogic 8.8 Professional\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar") as having no source attachment instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does it happen with default example models using the library? Does it happen with any other model?